# migrating mysql db to django, unique constraints?

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

Currently I have part of a model:

```
class Flight(models.Model):
    flight_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    airline_name = models.ForeignKey(Airline, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='airline_name')
    departure_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    departure_airport = models.ForeignKey(Airport, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='departure_airport', blank=True, null=True, related_name='departure_airport')
    arrival_airport = models.ForeignKey(Airport, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='arrival_airport', blank=True, null=True, related_name='arrival_airport')
    arrival_datetime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    airplane = models.ForeignKey(Airplane, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    base_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    flight_status = models.CharField(max_length=9)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'flight'
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['flight_number', 'airline_name', 'departure_datetime'], name='unique_flight')
        ]

class Ticket(models.Model):
    ticket_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, models.DO_NOTHING)
    flight_number = models.ForeignKey(Flight, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='flight_number', to_field='flight_number', related_name='ticket_flight_number')
    airline_name = models.ForeignKey(Flight, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='airline_name', to_field='airline_name', related_name='ticket_airline_name')
    departure_datetime = models.ForeignKey(Flight, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='departure_datetime', to_field='departure_datetime', related_name='ticket_departure_datetime')
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'ticket'
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['flight_number', 'airline_name', 'departure_datetime', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'date_of_birth'], name='unique_ticket')
        ]
```

But I keep getting the error log while trying to run migrate:

```
ERRORS:
atrsapp.Ticket.airline_name: (fields.E311) 'Flight.airline_name' must be unique because it is referenced by a foreign key.
        HINT: Add unique=True to this field or add a UniqueConstraint (without condition) in the model Meta.constraints.
atrsapp.Ticket.departure_datetime: (fields.E311) 'Flight.departure_datetime' must be unique because it is referenced by a foreign key.
        HINT: Add unique=True to this field or add a UniqueConstraint (without condition) in the model Meta.constraints.
```

I already had to change a few things (add related names) when trying to migrate after running inspectdb, but these two errors would not go away. I tried doing the inline unique = True to no avail.. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you know that we can have multiple of Flight with same foreign key to Airline and Airport, so when you create a foreign key on the Ticket to Flight and reference it to a foreign key form Flight it becomes a issues because we can a lot Flight with same foreign on Flight and it like we have many to many relationship, for this propose you can make unique theses field on Flight field unique or easily only make a foreign key to Flight id and when needs that data make a new query for them

Comment: thank you for the reply, so how would you suggest I fix it? I have tried adding unique constraints

Comment: @HenryKam create a new field with a foreign key to the Flight ID, and when you need the flight_number or the airline_name and departure_datetime just run a join to retrieve the data you need like this  Ticket.objects.first().flight_field.flight_number